# How to correctly support servlets in WildFly8.2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, wildfly

My problem is when adding WildFly 8.x Runtime in targeted runtimes in eclipse, then I can't run servlets, I mean the server runtime library is not in the path.
can you provide me with help.
I'm running ubuntu 14.10, eclips luna, JRE 1.8 and WildFly 8.2.0.
note: I don't want to manually add the servlet-api jar file.
Thank's in advance.

Edit1:
I found that not only the servlet implementation part is not loaded, but all other modules of WildFly, so this ensures me that the problem is in the whole server runtime!

Edit2:
as stated here in [2.1.1. Installing a new runtime section,](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/as/html/runtimes_servers.html#InstNewRuntime)

> You will also note a Deploy-Only Runtime type. This type does not provide a classpath for WTP projects. It is used solely by it's server type for the purpose of setting up a deploy directory for users who do not wish to make use of starting, stopping, or debugging their projects inside Eclipse.

can I conclude that my version is has a "deploy-only runtime type", but it's Version 8.2.0.Final    2014-11-20  Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK now, I just installed JbossAS Tools, which is described in eclipse as follows:

> Provides WTP server adapters for JBoss installations. These adapters are capable of deployment and providing classpaths for projects

then I could specify project runtime for new projects directly, or add WildFly runtime as a server library from build path for old projects.